# Store values in python without dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I have with me two values like p and q where p is an integer and q is a string.
I  need a data structure to store such values as `(p,q)` in python and the structure should be like I have to sort it in the future and print out first n elements.
I have tried `dictionaries` but after sorting I couldn't display the first n elements as the `dictionary` is an unordered list.
I won't be changing the values in the future.

Comment: A list of 2-tuples?

Comment: Tuples will do the job.  If you want the access methods of a dictionary, take a look at `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: I'd recommend `collections.namedtuple`

Comment: If it's an integer and a string, what is there to sort?

Comment: @K.Nielson Remember that the `OrderedDict` is ordered by insertion time, not by key.

Comment: @KlausD. That is a limitation.  I had imagined the sort taking place and the `OrderedDict` being constructed in order of the sorted keys.  But he does say, "I have to sort it in the future," so this invalidates my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 2d array. 
I am assuming the p and q are list with the same length. have a look to the code below.

```
p = [1,5,7,3,5,7,45,23]
q = ['one', 'five', 'seven', 'three', 'five', 'seven', 'forty five', 'twenty three']

array = [[ 0  for x in range(2)] for y in range(len(p))]


for index, val in enumerate(p):
  array[index][0]  = val
  array[index][1] = q[index]


print "first five to display:"
for i in range(5):
  print str(array[i][0]) + " - " + array[i][1]

print
print "sorted array by the integer"
for val in sorted(array):
 print str(val[0]) + " - " + val[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

OrderedDict objects
Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.